# I need actual integer types from my CakePHP JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs, cakephp

So I have an application using angular in the frontend and CakePHP in on the server. For the two way binding of angular to work properly my javascript variables need to be of the same type. Since I'm using integer id properties in many places, this fails often.

I also need to perform a number of calculations using data coming from the server.

The problem is that CakePHP serializes numerical types as strings. I've attempted to create recursive function to assign the proper types after each query, but it's failing in some cases.

```
function is_assoc($var)
    {
        return is_array($var) && array_diff_key($var,array_keys(array_keys($var)));
    }

function afterFind($results, $primary = false){

    if(is_array($results) && !$this->is_assoc($results)){
        foreach($results as $index => &$result){
            $result = $this->afterFind($result);
        }
    }
    elseif ($this->is_assoc($results)){
        foreach($results as $key => &$value){
            if(is_array($value)){
                $value = $this->afterFind($value);
            }
            else{
                $value = $this->convert($key, $value);
            }
        }
    }
    return $results;
}

function convert($key, $value){
    $columnTypes = $this->getColumnTypes();

    if($columnTypes[$key] === 'integer'){
        $value = (int)$value;
    }

    return $value;
}
```

This code works in many cases but fails when Json has the following structure:

```
{
    "countries": [
        {
            "Country": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Canada"
            },
            "Port": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "country_id": 1,
                    "name": "Vancouver"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In this case, the ports array is returned empty:

```
{
    "countries": [
        {
            "Country": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Canada"
            },
            "Port": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Can someone please help me find the error in my code.

Comment: What have you done to debug?  Your code examples don't really show how the functions are actually called, so it is unclear where you are having problems?

Comment: The afterFind function is called automatically by CakePHP after queries are executed. I'm coming into CakePHP and PHP in general pretty fresh so I'm hoping someone who knows a little more about this than I do can help out. For the time being I've just manually cast the numbers I need to integers.

Comment: PHP: `intval()`, JS: `parseInt()`. `(int)` results in pretty much the same thing, might be you are looking to convert on the JS end.

Comment: @MrYellow Will parsing on the js side have the similar performance?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? I've been using AngularJS/CakePHP/JSON without any problems. I don't bother converting IDs to integer, but keep them as strings. AngularJS does not care. Passing the ID back to Cake, and PHP does not care because it has automatic type conversion. So what's the problem?

Comment: Well it might be that the JS side is your problem. The variable on the server is a different variable to that on the client. If the type on the client is wrong, then it needs to be fixed on the client. The types don't persist from a PHP variable to a JS one. `console.log()` on the client to see what you're dealing with.